# Counting rows from 2 MySQL tables JOIN with 3th and ORDER BY highest counting result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

I'm trying to count posts from 2 tables and join the third table where I keep names, but I really have trouble with this..

```
T1 - id, message, id_users
T2 - id, reply, id_users
T3 - id, name
```

T1 there are only topics, T2 there are only replies to topics, T3 there are user's info like names..

I want make stats, which user have the most posts (including topics), something like this:

```
user1 - 454 total (topics + posts)
user2 - 421 total (topics + posts)
```

and so on..

I can't really make a SQL to do this, nothing I know won't work, and can't figure out, what I might write to ORDER BY set to make ORDER from highest posts to lowest..

Comment: please add what you had tried to question

Comment: I tried many variation and nothing works.. it's my shame, but I never use brackets, so I never come close to resolve this.. the issue is resolved, so I rather be to don't post my stupid tryouts.. it's been really stupid with comparing to functional query..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `UNION` of `T1` & `T2`and then join the resutlt with `T3`, finally do a `GROUP BY` to `COUNT` the number of posts, like this:

```
SELECT names, COUNT(*) as posts
FROM T3
JOIN (
   SELECT id_users FROM T1
   UNION All
   SELECT id_users FROM T2
) as t
ON T3.id = t.id_users
GROUP BY id_users
```

Comment: can you tell me pls, how can I use this count(*) row in PHP ? with this -> while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $row(what to display count?!) }

Comment: @TichomírDuchaplný Sorry my knowledge of PHP is very limited. I may not be able to answer your query correctly. You may try `$row[1]`

Comment: ok thx, I try something.. so help me pls understand this SQL, I want order it from the highest posts to lowest, but if I write GROUP BY 2, I get this issue "Can't group on 'posts'".. I can't order it by id or name, I need to order it by this count posts but it's don't work, what should I do ?

Comment: @TichomírDuchaplný add `ORDER BY posts DESC` after `GROUP BY id_users`

Answer (score 0):

```
select t3.name, count(*) from 
t3 inner join
     (select id_users from t1
     union all 
     select id_users from t2) as posts
on posts.id_users=t3.id
group by 1
```